# How to create a Powerset of MSetList?

Tags: coq

I am creating an `MSetList` `P` with elements of type `String`, and I would like to obtain the Powerset of P. I am not being able to figure it out.

Code below.

Thanks for your help :-)

```
Require Import 
        Coq.MSets.MSetList
        Coq.Strings.String 
        Coq.Structures.OrdersEx.

Module set := Make OrdersEx.String_as_OT.

Definition P := set.add "A"%string (set.add "B"%string (set.add "C"%string (set.add "D"%string set.empty))).

Compute P.
```

Answer (score 0):

[Answer was provided on the Coq Discourse Forum](https://coq.discourse.group/t/how-to-create-a-powerset-of-msetlist/1571/2) by [Yves Bertot](https://coq.discourse.group/u/ybertot/summary)

> The construction of set shows that you are using the `Make` function
> with a module as argument. If you type `Print Make`., you see that
> this is a functor taking a module of type `OrderedType` as argument,
> and it produces a module with many fields, among which `t`, `eq`,
> `eq_equiv`, `lt`, `lt_strorder`, `lt_compat`, `compare`,
> `compare_spec`, and `eq_dec`. If you type `Print OrderedType.`, you
> see that these field are the ones required to make an `OrderedType`.
>
> So Make constructs all the fields that would be required to call Make
> again, thus producing the powerset.
>
> You can just type :
>
> `Module pset := Make set.`
>
> and you will simply obtain a structure of sets, whose elements are in
> `set.t`. The following example was tested with coq 8.15.
>
> ```
>     Require Import 
>             Coq.MSets.MSetList
>             Coq.Strings.String 
>             Coq.Structures.OrdersEx.
>     
>     Module set := Make OrdersEx.String_as_OT.
>     
>     Module pset := Make set.
>     
>     Definition set1 := set.add "A"%string set.empty.
>     Definition set2 := set.add "B"%string set.empty.
>     Definition set3 := set.add "C"%string set1.
>     
>     Definition pset1 := pset.add set1 (pset.add set2 pset.empty).
>     
>     Compute pset.mem set3 pset1.
>     Compute pset.mem set2 pset1.
> ```